# Playing with scss functions

Tags: function, for-loop, sass

So I got the following code set up. Why is the last label not changing color from gray to red? When I add 1 to the totalTabs variable, it does change color, but that seems odd to me.
Perhaps it's a small typo somewhere, but I'm not seeing it...

```
<div class="tabs">  
  <input id="tab1" type="radio" name="tabs" checked/>
  <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs"/>
  <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs"/>
  <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs"/>
  <div class="tabs__labels">
    <label for="tab1">tab 001</label>
    <label for="tab2">tab 002</label>
    <label for="tab3">tab 003</label>
    <label for="tab4">tab 004</label>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs__items">
   <div class="tabs__item">lorem ipsum dolor tab 001</div>
   <div class="tabs__item">lorem ipsum dolor tab 002</div>
   <div class="tabs__item">lorem ipsum dolor tab 003</div>
   <div class="tabs__item">lorem ipsum dolor tab 004</div>
 </div>
```

And the styling so far...

```
.tabs {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;

  &__labels label {
    cursor: pointer;

    &:not(:last-child) {
      margin-right: 2rem;
    }
  }

  &__item {
    padding: 2rem 0;
  }

  // the magic
  $totalTabs: 4;

  @for $i from 0 to $totalTabs {
    [type=radio]:nth-child(#{$i}):checked ~ &__labels label:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        color: red;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So that was a doozy.. it should be from...through, in stead of from...to

Answer (score 0):

This line:

`@for $i from 0 to $totalTabs {`

Should be the following:

`@for $i from 0 through $totalTabs {`

The `to` keyword stops the loop at 1 index short of the length of your list.

Comment: I found this out due to a comment of a colleague, but forgot to mention it here. Thanks for the comment though...

Answer (score 0):

Changing 'to' in 'through' solved this issue... Thanks for the comment